# Sorting tuples with heapq

Tags: python, python-3.x, heapsort

I'm using [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module to heap-sort a list of tuples.

However, for tie on the first tuple's key, heapq does not auto fallback to the next key:

```
import heapq
x = [(3, 0, 0), (6, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1)]
heapq.heapify(x)
print(x)
```

Will print:

```
[(2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 0, 0), (6, 0, 1)]
```

I expect `(3, 0, 0)` should come before `(3, 1, 1)`. Do I need to specify a customized comparison method? or how do I make this work?

Comment: `sorted(x)` should give correct result.

Comment: You forgot to sort.

Comment: heap is not sorted state; `vals = list(reversed(range(10)))` then `heapq.heapify(vals)` would give `[0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 9, 6, 8]` - you might need to find out more for what heap is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states,

> its smallest element is always the root, heap[0]

but that doesn't mean that the other elements are ordered. After calling `heapify()`, you get

```
[(2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 0, 0), (6, 0, 1)]
```

When you remove the first (smallest) item, the heap will reorder itself:

```
heapq.heappop(x) # returns (2, 1, 0)
print(x)
```

gives

```
[(3, 0, 0), (3, 1, 1), (6, 0, 1)]
```

To get the full ordered list, implement a `heapsort()` function as described in the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#basic-examples).

Answer (score 0):

To sort the tuples list using the `heapq` module, you could implement the `heapsort()` function as shown in the [Basic Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#basic-examples) section of the documentation:

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def heapsort(iterable):
    h = []
    for value in iterable:
        heappush(h, value)
    return [heappop(h) for i in range(len(h))]

x = [(3, 0, 0), (6, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1)]

res = heapsort(x)
print(res)  # -> [(2, 1, 0), (3, 0, 0), (3, 1, 1), (6, 0, 1)]
```

As you can see, `(3, 0, 0)` will come before `(3, 1, 1)` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out when you pring the heap directly, the order is different than the order when you pop them sequentially. Though when you print it, the second/third element is not soreted, however they are INDEED sorted when you pop them in order:

```
import heapq
x = [(3, 0, 0), (6, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1)]
heapq.heapify(x)
while x:
    print(heapq.heappop(x))
```

produces:

```
(2, 1, 0)
(3, 0, 0) # middle element is 0, comes before 1 in the next
(3, 1, 1)
(6, 0, 1)
```